# Laravel5 and GAE using multiple queues

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am running a Laravel 5.1 project on Google App Engine.

To speed up the process, I found a package providing interfaces between GAE and Laravel5 implementations. (https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5)

Now, I would like to handle certain type of jobs differently. Different reattempts or failure handling. Also, I don't want certain type of jobs to interfere with others just by sitting in the queue.

To do this, my guess is to use multiple queues.
In the implementation of shpasser package, it seems that only one queue connection can be used. But the documentation of both GAE and Laravel 5 support multiple queues.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From inspecting [Shpasser/GaeSupportL5/Queue/GaeQueue.php](https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5/blob/5.1/src/Shpasser/GaeSupportL5/Queue/GaeQueue.php) it appears capable of supporting multiple queues, see [line #88](https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5/blob/5.1/src/Shpasser/GaeSupportL5/Queue/GaeQueue.php#L88-Lundefined):

```
return $task->add($this->getQueue($queue));
```

In the context of this method, this is passing the specified queue name to add() (from the GAE [TaskQueue API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push)) or 'default' if nothing is specified.

As a workaround you could also utilize the GAE TaskQueue API directly.